# Evitar error en consulta linq al obtener un valor null

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta, con la cual pretendo obtener el ultimo recibo ingresado por el usuario logeado en el sistema y añadirlo en un `Textbox`

```
var obtenerUltimoRecibo = db.abonoes.Where(a => a.id_usuario == id_usuarioLogeado)
                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.id_abono).First().rec_menbrete;

TextBoxReciboMenbrete.Text = Convert.ToString(obtenerUltimoRecibo + 1);
```

mi consulta funciona perfecta siempre y cuando se cumpla la condicion establecida.

Tengo el siguiente caso:
Hay muchos abonos en esa tabla en los que el campo `id_usuario` el valor es `null` y lo que pretendo es que no me genere un error la consulta, si no que saque un null

me arroja el siguiente error

> La secuencia no contiene elementos

Comment: Te genera el error a la hora de recebir null en `obtenerUltimoRecibo` o al convertir `ToString`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas haciendo uso de [Enumerable.First](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.7.2), que [según la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.7.2) si no encuentra ningún elemento, producirá un [ArgumentNullException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Para solucionarlo, podrías usar [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2), ya que en este caso, si no se encuentra ningún elemento, simplemente devolverá null.

Teniendo en cuenta esto, podrías aplicarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
//Obtenes el objeto o null usando FirstOrDefault
var obj = db.abonoes.Where(a => a.id_usuario == id_usuarioLogeado)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.id_abono).FirstOrDefault();

//Si el objeto no es nulo, realizas la acción
if(obj != null)
{
    var obtenerUltimoRecibo = obj.rec_menbrete;
    TextBoxReciboMenbrete.Text = Convert.ToString(obtenerUltimoRecibo + 1);
}
//Caso contario, manejas la situación de que el objeto sea nulo
else
{
    //manejas el ciclo del software siendo obj nulo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vas a tener qu validarlo, puediendo ser el caso que obtengas null

```
int ultimoRecibo = 0;

var abono = db.abonoes.Where(a => a.id_usuario == id_usuarioLogeado)
                        .OrderByDescending(a => a.id_abono)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
if(abono != null)   
{   
    ultimoRecibo = abono.rec_menbrete;
}

ultimoRecibo++;

TextBoxReciboMenbrete.Text = ultimoRecibo.ToString();
```

Tambien podrias evaluar usar `Max()`, algo como ser

```
int ultimoRecibo = db.abonoes.Where(a => a.id_usuario == id_usuarioLogeado)
                             .Select(x => x.rec_menbrete)
                             .DefaultIfEmpty()
                             .Max();

ultimoRecibo++;

TextBoxReciboMenbrete.Text = ultimoRecibo.ToString();
```